# Read file to String when a new document is created in Chromium?

Tags: chromium

I am looking to read a file to string so that I can execute it's contents (JS) when any new document (tab, iframe, etc) is created.

**This is not an Extension but C++ code being built into a standalone binary**

I have the following code -

```cpp
InjectionRenderFrameObserver::DidCreateNewDocument(){
       std::string jq;
       base::FilePath path("jQuery.js");
       LOG(INFO) << "FilePath::" << path.value();
       if(base::PathExists(path)){
         LOG(INFO) << "FileExists::";
       }
       if(!base::ReadFileToString(path, &jq)){
         LOG(ERROR) << "Can't read content of '" << path.value() << "'.";
       }
    }
```

The Console logs the following:

```
[967856:1:1122/1950927.423702:INFO:injection_render_frame_observer.cc(16)] FilePath::jQuery.js
[967856:1:1122/1950927.423981:INFO:injection_render_frame_observer.cc(20)] Can't read content of 'jQuery.js'.
```

I haven't been able to connect a debugger to it yet (having some system issues) but was wondering if there is an obvious issue that would prevent the above from working that I am missing since the Chromium Dev wiki/knowledge space is limited for new developers (or at least I haven't found a good source yet).

The above code is my example code (what I am starting with) to get a file loaded. The end goal will be a feature switch that allows a default or provided path to script that will run before each document is created.

Comment: Is that code being executed by the browser process or render process?

Comment: @Asesh - the Render process

Comment: Based on your comment @Asesh, I presume that the render process is sandboxed out of the file system since it doesn't (or really shouldn't) need access to it and I should probably be reading the file during browser process, storing it to a shared memory location and referencing it in the render process? If so, do you know of any examples to hook into the Browser process?

Comment: You should Chromium's IPC to send data from browser process to render process and vice-versa. More info: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication